# remove an item using bulk update

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-bulk-api

I have an object with different values in Elasticsearch. When I want to update it, I use bulk api like below:

```
inventory_edition.append(
 {    
  '_op_type': 'update',
  '_index': value_index,
  '_id': object['inventory.id'],
  '_source': {'doc': object}
 }
)
```

It update previous items whom I call them and also add new items but I dont know how to remove a previous item whom I'm not calling it!
How can I remove a previous item in editing object using bulk api?

```
"hits" : [
   {
     "_index" : "index-name",
     "_type" : "_doc",
     "_id" : "list144bbfba447b9552ece89391d075",
     "_score" : 1.2039728,
     "_source" : {
       "inventory.name" : "list1-edit",
       "inventory.type" : "ip",
       "inventory.description" : "description",
       "inventory.id" : "list144bbfba447b9552ece89391d075"
     }
   }
 ]
```

Comment: what do you mean by it does not remove previous item? do you mean you have two doc with same _id or what?

Comment: could you share an example of new and old doc?

Comment: for example I wanna remove `"inventory.type"` in elasticsearch:
`"_source" : {
       "inventory.name" : "list1-edit",
       "inventory.description" : "description",
       "inventory.id" : "list144bbfba447b9552ece89391d075"
     }`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this way..
I used delete and create in bulk api instead of update.

```
inventory_edition.append(
 {
  '_op_type': 'delete',
  '_index': value_index,
  '_id': object['inventory.id'],
 }
)

object[lablabla..] = lablabla..

inventory_edition.append(
 {
  '_op_type': 'create',
  '_index': value_index,
  '_id': object['inventory.id'],
  '_source': object
 }
)

self.es.remove_index(index = value_index)
self.es.check_index(value_index) // this function create new value_index
self.es.bulk_es(self.es.ES_CLIENT, inventory_edition)
```